# Health system script not running in Unity; no errors or Debug.Log statements popping up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my health system in a Unity game, I have a script that is accountable for my in-game "enemy" hit-points. The game runs just fine, but the script doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not getting any error messages, but the fact that it's not working and Debug.Log statements aren't popping up in console seem to be that functions aren't being called properly or that something else is awry. Here is my script:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
public class Health : MonoBehaviour {
private float hitPoints = 5;
    // Health popup
    void announceUp()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("If this message shows in Debug.Log, the script should be working.");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The enemy has been hit!");
                hitPoints = hitPoints - 1f;
                if (hitPoints == 0f)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The enemy has been eliminated!");
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've poked around the internet to see what's wrong, but I couldn't find anything. Could someone inform me on what could be wrong with my programming?

Comment: Put the `OnTriggerEnter` Function out of your Update Method.

Comment: That gives me an error saying a closing curly bracket is missing even though it's there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scrpt is currently not working, because you are defining the [`OnTriggerEnter()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) Method inside the [`Update()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) Method. When you do that you are defining a local function and Unity then can't call that function when actual collision happens. So your [`OnTriggerEnter()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) Function never get's called.

Example:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float hitPoints = 5;
    // Health popup
    void announceUp() {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("If this message shows in Debug.Log, 
            the script should be working.");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {}

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The enemy has been hit!");
            hitPoints = hitPoints - 1f;
            if (hitPoints == 0f) {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The enemy has been eliminated!");
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then there is a problem with your collision. Check that the objet containing OnTriggerEnter actually has IsTrigger enabled and that both object have a box collider and rigidbody.

Comment: The parent object in which the script is attached to does not have a rigidbody, but as the "enemy" is a ragdoll all of its bones have the components which you mentioned. When it is shot at it does interact with the bullet, though (ex: flopping around).

Comment: Are you sure the enemy has IsTrigger enabled because if he doesn't you would need to use OnCollisionEnter instead.

Comment: Nope! It wasn't enabled, but now it's working great! Thanks!